# how to compare 2 word file?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I've a 2 ms word file and both has almost same content? I just want to see any changes between documents in content. if is there any.

can anyone tell me a simple way?

Answer (score 3):

Tutorial: [Comparing Two Versions of a Word Document](http://www.codejacked.com/comparing-two-versions-of-a-word-document/)

Comment: Nice tutorial. I updated my answer with the `-xw` options for `catdoc` from the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

From [How to Compare Word Documents Side by Side](http://www.ehow.com/how_2170916_compare-word-documents-side-side.html) :

1. In Word, open the two documents you want to compare.
2. Choose Window.
3. Click "Compare Side by Side With" (it will also list the name of the second document, or simply say "Document2"). If you have more than two documents open, a dialog box will open allowing you to choose your second document.
4. You will see a "Compare Side by Side" toolbar. The "Synchronous Scrolling" will allow you to scroll through both documents at the same time.
5. If you want your documents to reset to their original positions, click the "Reset Window Position" button.
6. When you are finished comparing your documents, click "Close Side by Side".

Image for Word 2003:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you on Unix/Linux/MacOSX (or using cygwin), using `catdoc`:

```
diff -u <(catdoc -xw /path/to/doc1.doc) <(catdoc -xw /path/to/doc2.doc)
```

It won't give you the formatting diff, just the text and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is open both the files you want to compare.

Right click on the task bar menu.In that select Tile Windows Horizontally or Tile Windows Vertically as you wish.Both the documents will be compared horizontally or vertically.