# How can I productively find text that appears identically between different Word documents?

Tags: microsoft-word

It's too unproductive to try to eye-ball text, especially across different long documents! Can Word search them all, then list all text that's identical?
For instance, exchange-traded fund (ETF) providers list their portfolios in PDFs that I'll save as Word documents. How can I compare all these Word documents to see which ETFs appear in more than one Word document (or ETF)?

[how to compare 2 word file?](https://superuser.com/q/87285) doesn't answer my question, because I'm asking about two different Word files that don't have the same content. The latest answers are from 2009, and I'd hope there are better solutions in 2020?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the build-in feature Find & Replace to manually search the content and Highlight All match items over multiple documents:

[image]

Word will tell you the numbers of match items. Collect the numbers in different documents. Then, you can compare the numbers in different documents and get the result you want.
[image]

For your reference:[Find and replace text](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-and-replace-text-c6728c16-469e-43cd-afe4-7708c6c779b7); [Generating a Count of Word Occurrences](https://word.tips.net/T001833_Generating_a_Count_of_Word_Occurrences.html).

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand your answer. How does your answer compare different documents? You input "Word".